# SharePoint Online provider host Send Email - Access denied

Tags: email, permissions, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-addin

I'm developing a SharePoint Provider hosted Add-ins using CSOM and I'm having Access Denied when sending a email using:

```
EmailProperties emailProperties = new EmailProperties();
emailProperties.To = emailAddresses;
emailProperties.From = "no-reply@sharepointonline.com";
emailProperties.Body = @"XXXXX";
emailProperties.Subject = viagem.Title;

Utility.SendEmail(context, emailProperties);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

> [ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have
>   permission to perform this action or access this resource.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream) +2911
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse() +1564

The App already has some permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/bcs/connection" Right="Read" />
```

I have two questions:

1- What permissions do I need to add?

2- I'm trying to use "no-reply@sharepointonline.com" as the sender because that's the address  used in workflows as sender. 
Anyone knows what is the default email for email messages in SharePoint Online?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solve it.

1 - Site collection permissions.

2 - I can use the "no-reply@sharepointonline.com"